# SharePoint custom forms are slow and unresponsive

Tags: sharepoint-designer, form, classic-experience

Since September our SharePoint Custom forms (created with SP designer) became extremely slow, often unresponsive.

They have been working fine for 5 years. I guess Microsoft is changing something.

Does anybody have similar issue or information about it?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint online

Answer (score 1):

If you have not made any recent changes to your forms, then I would recommend contacting Microsoft support. You can open a ticket with Microsoft from the Microsoft 365 admin center. Since SharePoint Online is software-as-a-service (SaaS), only Microsoft will be able to look at detailed performance data pertaining to your tenant.

There is some limited information that you can gather from the response headers in your browser. You can check these by going to the network tab in Chrome (or whichever browser you use) and select the page e.g. yourtenant.sharepoint.com and view the response headers for it. These will include:

- Spiislatency
- Sprequestduration
- X-Sharepointhealthscore

Low latency and request duration is good. The lower the SharePoint health score, the better (the score is from 0 to 10).